# how to implement span tag in an array to html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

```
let array= ["<span style="font-weight:900">everthing</span> is perfect", "Look for opportunities in <span style="font-weight:900">every</span>change"]

array.map((arr) => {
          return (
              <div>
                {arr}
              </div>
          );
        })
```

Desired output:

**everthing** is perfect
Look for opportunities in **every** change

My output:

```
<span style="font-weight:900">everthing</span> is perfect 
Look for opportunities in <span style="font-weight:900">every</span>change
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install a package for that.

```
yarn add react-html-parser
npm install react-html-parser
```

then.

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser'; 
<div> { array.map((arr)=>(
    {ReactHtmlParser (arr)}
)) } </div>
```

Comment: Thank you bro. however the npm install react-html-parser works only for react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0".. but thank you for suggesting me such idea. I found npm install html-react-parser --save for the version 17.0.2. Once again thanks bro